# Configuring multiple ISP routers on a PA-850

Tags: networking, firewall, palo-alto-networks

I am researching an configuration for our Palo-Alto 850 firewalls. We currently have 4 ISP  routers coming into our facility (1x MPLS/Fiber, 1x cable and 2 DSL). We would like to connect these to a L3 switch so we can setup vLans and from there run a fiber to our PA-850 HA set. Is it possible to create 4 virtual routers on the PA and assign each a route to a specific vLan/ISP router.

I have researched the PA documentation and it lists a multiple ISP option up to 2 connections but specifically configured for connection failover, not for just separating traffic streams based on source/target vLans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with that specific Palo Alto, I'd say that you can create however many virtual routers you want in PANOS, but you'll need to do quite a bit of config work to get them to route traffic to the WAN links properly. Virtual routers are inherently separate so if you links are used for specific purposes it wouldn't be too hard. Also look into if you can get a routing protocol to work with the ISP routers, it's quite a lot easier and neater if you can get route advertisements from the ISP routers.

Also keep in mind the bandwidth limitations of the PA-850 so that you aren't asking them to handle more traffic than they are capable of. PAs are quite conservative in their estimates, and their ratings are "with every security feature turned on", but still do keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We intend to use each ISP connection for specific purposes. e.g. 1 for just backup VPN and guest WiFi traffic, 1 for in/out-bound LAN/Server traffic, etc... W'll be using a 802.1x/Raduis setup to 'direct' traffic. Our totaal connected bandwidth is approx. 50% of the total bandwidth capacity of the PA, but we don't use it at max. capacity most of the times, so we should be safe. Again thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Then it's fairly simple, just create a virtual router for each ISP, and connect an interface to each.